# we need to retrieve all the rows from mysql. And table has only a single column e.g name.Which approach is better?

Tags: php, mysql

Which of below query will be better to use if **table has single column**? Please also provide technical justification.

```
select * from table
```

or

```
select `name` from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Speed/execution be the same. Just because of future table changes (and clarity of the message) you should use second option.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is just placeholder for `all`; though there is no difference, because engine treats it like `name` in that case, but if some day you change table rows (add something, for example `surname`) it would be best choice, to use just `name` in `select` statement due to avoid future source-code changes.